# Mixed up raid 0 disks

Tags: raid, hard-drive

A friend of mine has removed 4 disks from 2 raid 0 arrays and can't remember which disk belongs to which.

Should she put them in wrong, is there potential for data loss to occur?

If so, how could she determine which disk belongs to which.

I have told her why raid 0 shouldn't be used in a production environment like hers.

Many Thanks

Matt

Comment: How was the RAID setup? HW RAID? If so which card? If software RAID: which OS, which RAID driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how the RAID was setup. Some hardware controllers write the array configuration to the drives. You can put those back in any order you like and the RAID controller will figure out which drives to use.

*Some*, not all.

The same is true of some software RAID implementations. E.g. in Linux you can query the status of a disk with the mdadm command. (Boot from a liveCD, insert a single drive and query. That way there is not risk of a 'helpful' autodetect and useage of the array.

For windows the same is probably true, though I do not have any experience with windows and non-hardware RAID.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not too sure what she's using so that's all the information I could give. I'll let her know cheers!